Laravel query not returning correct values
I am building an expense managing web app.
I have a section analytics and I am working on filters for that page.
The filter parameters are sent to the server correctly, but the problem is that the raw SQL query doesn't include those parameters for filtering.
My code:
async getCategories() {
                this.loading = true;

                const { response } = await this.request('GET', '/get-other-categories', { params: { userId: this.activeUser.id, ...this.filters } });

                this.categories = response.data;
                this.expenses = this.categories.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.total_expenses, 0);
                
                this.loading = false;
            },
            async getIncomeCategory() {
                this.loading = true;

                const { response } = await this.request('GET', '/get-income-category', { params: { userId: this.activeUser.id, ...this.filters } });

                this.incomeCategories = response.data;
                this.income = this.incomeCategories.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.total_income, 0);

                this.loading = false;
            },

filterRecordsByAccounts(accounts) {
                const selectedAccounts = [...new Set(accounts)];

                if (!selectedAccounts.length) {
                    this.filters.accounts = [];

                    this.getCategories();
                    this.getIncomeCategory();

                    return;
                }

                this.filters.accounts = selectedAccounts;

                this.getCategories();
                this.getIncomeCategory();
            },

 public function getIncomeCategory(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $userId = $request->query('userId');
        $startDate = $request->query('startDate');
        $endDate = $request->query('endDate');
        $accountIds = $request->query('accounts', []);
        $categoryIds = $request->query('categories', []);
        $labels = $request->query('labels', []);
        $types = $request->query('types', []);
        $paymentTypes = $request->query('paymentTypes', []);
        $paymentStatuses = $request->query('paymentStatuses', []);

        Log::info('received-parameters', [
            'userId' => $userId,
            'startDate' => $startDate,
            'endDate' => $endDate,
            'accountIds' => $accountIds,
            'categoryIds' => $categoryIds,
            'labels' => $labels,
            'types' => $types,
            'paymentTypes' => $paymentTypes,
            'paymentStatuses' => $paymentStatuses,
        ]);

        $query = Category::with(['children' => function ($query) use ($userId, $startDate, $endDate, $accountIds, $categoryIds, $labels, $types, $paymentTypes, $paymentStatuses) {
            $query->where('visible', true)
                ->with(['children' => function ($query) use ($userId, $startDate, $endDate, $accountIds, $categoryIds, $labels, $types, $paymentTypes, $paymentStatuses) {
                    $query->where('user_id', $userId)
                        ->where('visible', true)
                        ->with(['records' => function ($query) use ($userId, $startDate, $endDate, $accountIds, $categoryIds, $labels, $types, $paymentTypes, $paymentStatuses) {
                            $query->where('user_id', $userId)
                                ->whereBetween('date', [$startDate, $endDate])
                                ->when($accountIds, function ($query, $accountIds) {
                                    $query->whereIn('account_id', $accountIds);
                                })
                                ->when($categoryIds, function ($query, $categoryIds) {
                                    $query->whereIn('category_id', $categoryIds);
                                })
                                ->whereHas('labels', function ($q) use ($labels) {
                                    $q->whereIn('label_id', $labels);
                                })
                                ->when($types, function ($query, $types) {
                                    $query->whereIn('type', $types);
                                })
                                ->when($paymentTypes, function ($query, $paymentTypes) {
                                    $query->whereIn('payment_type', $paymentTypes);
                                })
                                ->when($paymentStatuses, function ($query, $paymentStatuses) {
                                    $query->whereIn('payment_status', $paymentStatuses);
                                });
                        }]);
                }]);
        }])
        ->whereNull('parent_id')
        ->where('visible', true)
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->whereRaw("json_extract(name, '$.en') = 'Income'")
                ->orWhereRaw("json_extract(name, '$.lv') = 'Ienākumi'");
        });

        Log::info('query', [$query->toSql()]);

        $categories = $query->get();
        
        return response()->json(CategoryResource::collection($categories));
    }

    public function getOtherCategories(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $userId = $request->query('userId');
        $startDate = $request->query('startDate');
        $endDate = $request->query('endDate');
        $accountIds = $request->query('accounts', []);
        $categoryIds = $request->query('categories', []);
        $labels = $request->query('labels', []);
        $types = $request->query('types', []);
        $paymentTypes = $request->query('paymentTypes', []);
        $paymentStatuses = $request->query('paymentStatuses', []);

        Log::info('received-parameters', [
            'userId' => $userId,
            'startDate' => $startDate,
            'endDate' => $endDate,
            'accountIds' => $accountIds,
            'categoryIds' => $categoryIds,
            'labels' => $labels,
            'types' => $types,
            'paymentTypes' => $paymentTypes,
            'paymentStatuses' => $paymentStatuses,
        ]);

        $query = Category::with(['children' => function ($query) use ($userId, $startDate, $endDate, $accountIds, $categoryIds, $labels, $types, $paymentTypes, $paymentStatuses) {
            $query->where('visible', true)
                ->with(['children' => function ($query) use ($userId, $startDate, $endDate, $accountIds, $categoryIds, $labels, $types, $paymentTypes, $paymentStatuses) {
                    $query->where('user_id', $userId)
                        ->where('visible', true)
                        ->with(['records' => function ($query) use ($userId, $startDate, $endDate, $accountIds, $categoryIds, $labels, $types, $paymentTypes, $paymentStatuses) {
                            $query->where('user_id', $userId)
                                ->whereBetween('date', [$startDate, $endDate])
                                ->when($accountIds, function ($query, $accountIds) {
                                    $query->whereIn('account_id', $accountIds);
                                })
                                ->when($categoryIds, function ($query, $categoryIds) {
                                    $query->whereIn('category_id', $categoryIds);
                                })
                                ->whereHas('labels', function ($q) use ($labels) {
                                    $q->whereIn('label_id', $labels);
                                })
                                ->when($types, function ($query, $types) {
                                    $query->whereIn('type', $types);
                                })
                                ->when($paymentTypes, function ($query, $paymentTypes) {
                                    $query->whereIn('payment_type', $paymentTypes);
                                })
                                ->when($paymentStatuses, function ($query, $paymentStatuses) {
                                    $query->whereIn('payment_status', $paymentStatuses);
                                });
                        }]);
                }]);
        }])
        ->whereNull('parent_id')
        ->where('visible', true)
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->whereRaw("json_extract(name, '$.en') != 'Income'")
                ->orWhereRaw("json_extract(name, '$.lv') != 'Ienākumi'");
        });
        
        Log::info('query', [$query->toSql()]);

        $categories = $query->get();

        return response()->json(CategoryResource::collection($categories));
    }

The logs return this, when I try to filter by bank account:
[2024-07-05 02:44:21] local.INFO: received-parameters {"userId":"1","startDate":null,"endDate":null,"accountIds":["1"],"categoryIds":[],"labels":[],"types":[],"paymentTypes":[],"paymentStatuses":[]} 
[2024-07-05 02:44:21] local.INFO: query ["select * from `categories` where `parent_id` is null and `visible` = ? and (json_extract(name, '$.en') != 'Income' or json_extract(name, '$.lv') != 'Ienākumi') and `categories`.`deleted_at` is null"] 
[2024-07-05 02:44:24] local.INFO: received-parameters {"userId":"1","startDate":null,"endDate":null,"accountIds":["1"],"categoryIds":[],"labels":[],"types":[],"paymentTypes":[],"paymentStatuses":[]} 
[2024-07-05 02:44:24] local.INFO: query ["select * from `categories` where `parent_id` is null and `visible` = ? and (json_extract(name, '$.en') = 'Income' or json_extract(name, '$.lv') = 'Ienākumi') and `categories`.`deleted_at` is null"] 


laravel version?

"the raw SQL query doesn't include those parameters for filtering" - you are not filtering by those parameters, you are only limiting what gets eager-loaded. To check the query chain the ->dd() method to your most inner query in your with

Laravel version -  8.83.27.

But that's the point. I need to filter records eager loaded from category.

Any suggestions on how I could improve the query? @kris gjika

it's not clear what you are getting and what you want to get from your query, are you getting empty results or the wrong categories. maybe include a sample of this categories table you are querying. For example you are filtering on the second level of children, but I have no idea if your data is on the first or third level of children categories. Also note that $query->toSql() only includes your main query, and not the eager loads. if you want to log those, you need to log the inner $query withing your "with" closure. @screw4445

I want to get categories with records with added conditionals, for example having account_id with 2. I will post Category table.

I have a filter sidebar where I can select which attributes to include or exclude. For example I want to exclude from results bank account with id 2.

Field  Type  Null  Key  Default  Extra
id  bigint(20) unsigned  NO  PRI  NULL  auto_increment
icon  varchar(255)  NO   NULL
name  longtext  NO   NULL
visible  tinyint(1)  NO   1
color  varchar(255)  YES   NULL
parent_id  bigint(20) unsigned  YES  MUL  NULL
user_id  bigint(20) unsigned  YES  MUL  NULL
created_at  timestamp  YES   NULL
updated_at  timestamp  YES   NULL
deleted_at  timestamp  YES   NULL Sorry, I dont know how to format this @kris gjika

1  fas fa-utensils  {"en":"Food & Beverages","lv":"\u0112diens, dz\u01...  1  #db1507  NULL  NULL  2024-07-20 01:44:09  2024-07-20 01:44:09  NULL
Edit Edit  Copy Copy  Delete Delete  2  fas fa-utensils  {"en":"Food & Beverages","lv":"\u0112diens, dz\u01...  1  #db1507  1  NULL  2024-07-20 01:44:09  2024-07-20 01:44:09  NULL
Edit Edit  Copy Copy  Delete Delete  3  fas fa-glass-martini  {"en":"Bar, cafe","lv":"B\u0101rs, kafejn\u012bca"...  1  #db1507  1  NULL  2024-07-20 01:44:09  2024-07-20 01:44:09  NULL
